# xslt multi-part key grouping

Tags: xml, xslt, key, grouping

Lets say I have some xml like this:

```
<root>
<object id='1'/>
<object id='1' otherid='2'/>
<object otherid='2'/>
<object otherid='2' yetanotherid='3'/>
<object yetanotherid='3'/>
<object id='2'>I'm not the same</object>
</root>
```

Lovely, I know. Now these are all the same object, but they have an assortment of ids. How can I group them? Any of these id's will uniquely identify, so id[1]=otherid[2]=yetanotherid[3].

A complete example:

```
<root>
<object id='1'><property1></property1></object>
<object id='1' otherid='2'><property1></property1></object>
<object otherid='2'><property2></property2></object>
<object otherid='2' yetanotherid='3'><property3></property3></object>
<object yetanotherid='3'><property2></property2><property4></property4></object>
<object id='2'><property2></property2></object>
</root>
```

Outcome:

```
<root>
<object id='1' otherid='2' yetanotherid='3'>
<property1></property1>
<property2></property2>
<property3></property3>
<property4></property4>
</object>
<object id='2'>
<property2></property2>
</object>
</root>
```

Comment: Can you give a sample output please?

Comment: For this input, there would be two groups, first group would be the first 5 objects, second would be the last object. This would apply to my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680216/merging-elements-with-xsl/ where I am merging elements of the same object. I need to group the objects so I can merge them.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want to group them based only on the id attribute? It is still unclear to me how you want to group your elements. You can create 2 groups based on your id attribute but not all elements have it so the elements who don't have it get left out. What does : id[1]=otherid[2]=yetanotherid[3] mean?

Comment: Since one of the elements has both id=1 and otherid=2 we know that [id=1]=[otherid=2] and since another element has otherid=2 and yetanotherid=3 we know that [otherid=2]=[yetanotherid=3] and by extension that [id=1]=[yetanotherid=3]. Thus, all should be grouped together. How to do that evades me. We know this because the IDs uniquely identify, so if an element possesses 2, you know those are equivalent identifiers.